# WordPress by default Crop some of my Images

Tags: wordpress, playlist

```
<img class="blog-picture ul-normal-classic lazyloaded" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/JaoMeriGuriya300.jpg" alt="JaoMeriGuriya300" data-ll-status="loaded">
```

I'd call a playlist through elementor shortcode.
Some images are in normal size and some of them were crop by default and in the img src there (-300x203) I don't know why this happens.
I'd upload images using fileZilla.
I use js (which suggest me by a respected person in the last question) but it doesn't work

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            var allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.blog-picture.ul-normal-classic.lazyloaded');
            for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
                var imageSource = allImages[i].getAttribute('src');
                if (imageSource.includes('-300x203')) {
                    var replacedSource = allImages[i].getAttribute('src').replace('-300x203', '');
                    allImages[i].setAttribute('src', replacedSource);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try visiting `Settings » Media` in WordPress `admin area` and set the default image sizes to 0 it should prevent WordPress from generating default image sizes when you upload a new image. Also try removing `add_image_size` from `functions.php`

Comment: change in media doesn't work for me and remove the add_image_size will remove all the images of the web